# Noisy signal output from BD2320 MOSFET driver

Tags: power-electronics, pwm, buck, mosfet-driver

I need help or technical solutions relating to this issue I encountered with BD2320.

I intend to use two BD2320 drivers for an interleaved buck converter. One of the channels works well, but after implementing the second channel, the low side output of the BD2320 of both channels now has a lot of noise when the signal is high.

I could trace this issue to the capacitor used at the low side input of the driver. I used a 330 pF capacitor at the input to the driver (both LIN and HIN), but I only got a nice output from the driver when I removed the input capacitor at the LIN.

I have tried different values from 1 pF to 1 nF but the noise still persists.

The [datasheet](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/gate_driver/bd2320efj-la-e.pdf) can be found here.

Noisy signal:
[image: noisy signal]

Noiseless signal:
[image: noiseless signal]

I appreciate any help regarding this issue.

I will be adding the circuit diagram now below
[image: Mosfet driver BD2320]

Comment: Your circuit diagram added tothe question would be very helpful. Also read operational notes 10 and 11 on page 15 of the datasheet that is linked in the question.

Comment: Layout will likely be illuminating as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback, I have checked both operational notes and its been considered.